# files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited error how to resolve it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Without changing anything after making new project, when I run the app in android studio, it gives me this error:
[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: seem like you use appcompat-v7/26.0.0-alpha1. Is it correct ?

Comment: That is not an error. It a warning, letting you know that you shouldn't *modify* that XML file, as any change is likely to be discarded if you do a clean build.

Comment: i dont know about that but i am not making any changes all i am doing is creating a new project and then just running it

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by wrong support library version. If you are using androidx dependency, try to change to support lib.
Also, you are seeing the auto-generated xml file. You must declare your own xml file in your project folder.

Comment: i dont know anything bout that i downloded some tutorial and in that tutorial the version i am using of android studio is 1.1.0 and now i all i am doing is making new project and trying to run it but it giving me same error